# Using D3 to draw lines sequentially not simultaneously

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am drawing the lines of an SVG using the code from here: https://github.com/dcamilleri/F1Data-Circuit-SVG-Draw.

This piece of code specifically draws a line for each SVG path.

```
var paths = circuit.getElementsByTagName("path");

  for(var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {

    var length = parseInt(paths[i].getTotalLength());

    d3.select(paths[i])
      .style("stroke-dasharray", length)
      .style("stroke-dashoffset", length)
      .transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .ease('linear')
      .style("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
}
```

At the moment each line is drawn simultaneously over a 10 second period. What I want is to draw one line after the next is finished.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`transition.delay()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay) method which allows you to specify a delay. Because you're using i, you can probably just multiply it by the duration you have set.

```
d3.select(paths[i])
  .style("stroke-dasharray", length)
  .style("stroke-dashoffset", length)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .delay(10000*i)
  .ease('linear')
  .style("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```